# I2C (OLED SSD1306) on Orange Pi R1 Plus LTS with OpenWrt

Tags: python-3.x, openwrt, orange-pi

I'm new to OpenWrt but I have about a year of self-project (college final project, to be exact) experience using Linux in Raspberry Pi.

Have anyone here used I2C OLED SSD1306 on Orange Pi R1 Plus LTS with OpenWrt? I'm stuck now with the problem of enabling it.

I use OpenWrt 21.02.2, r16495-bf0c965af0.

Here's what I have tried: I used this library: https://github.com/karabek/OrangePi-OLED, and I tried to detect the i2c on bus 0 and 1 to get the device address,  and I ran the demo file from the library. I expected the device to be able to run the i2c device on the detected port and address correctly.

When I tried to detect the i2c on bus 0 and 1, here's the output:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# i2cdetect -y 0
Error: Could not open file `/dev/i2c-0' or `/dev/i2c/0': No such file or directory
```

```
root@OpenWrt:~# i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

And then I modified the demo file from the library:

```
device = ssd1306(port=1, address=0x18)
```

And I run it. Here's what I got

```
root@OpenWrt:/mnt/OrangePi-OLED/examples# python3 demo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/OrangePi-OLED/examples/demo.py", line 11, in <module>
    device = ssd1306(port=1, address=0x18)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oled/device.py", line 163, in __init__
    self.command(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oled/device.py", line 73, in command
    self.bus.write_i2c_block_data(self.addr, self.cmd_mode, list(cmd))
OSError: [Errno 16] Resource busy
```

I suspect this is because of the bus 0 is not enabled yet, as here is what the documentation says
[Orange Pi R1 Plus LTS Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0m3O.png)

But the OpenWrt version I'm using doesn't have the boot folder.

What is the solution?

Also, if it turns out I can't use I2C, what display should I use? Can I use SPI TFT IPS or UART display?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem on a Raspberry Pi 4b when I configured the i2c address. It is busy because the kernel has control of the device. My solution was to remove the address from the config file.
The 'i2cdetect -y 1' command confirms the i2c device is wired correct. After removing the added info from the library file and reboot rerun the 'i2cdetect -y 1' and see if the 'UU' is replaced with the correct address. if so, a python program can used to init it. If not, working with the kernel is way over my head.

Answer (score 0):

I thought that I added a python test program, but I don't see it now. I will try to add it now.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Program to Test and display date, time, month, day and year

"""
Tested only on (HiLetgo 1.3" IIC I2C Serial 128x64 SSH1106 SSD1306
  OLED LCD Display LCD Module for Arduino AVR PIC STM32), (Walfront 1.3
  Inch 128X64 IIC I2C SPI Serial OLED Display Module White Text Color
  for MP3 Function Cellphone Smart Health Device) and the
  (Raspberry Pi 4B 32bit). These displays only has page mode.

PREREQ:
  The i2c display connected to i2c GPIO pins, 3.3v & gnd.
  The /boot/config.txt has: dtparam=i2c_arm=on,i2c_arm_baudrate=400000
  The shell command  ls -l /dev/i2c*, shows /dev/i2c-1.
  The shell command  i2cdetect -y 1, shows the device address.
  
NOTE:
  The i2c display device does not have a reset, so registers and 
  display memory may be in any state (garbage on the display).

This program will put the device in a known state.
  Set display on, ram on, normal and page mode.
  Run some test, clear ram and turn display off (sleep).
  Adjust varibles and program to your needs.

https://pinout.xyz/pinout/i2c
https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/11/enabling-the-i2c-interface-on-the-raspberry-pi/
https://www.pololu.com/file/0J1813/SH1106.pdf
https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/e/e3/1.3inch-SH1106-OLED.pdf
https://www.electronicwings.com/sensors-modules/ssd1306-oled-display
https://docs.kernel.org/i2c/smbus-protocol.html
https://www.digikey.com/htmldatasheets/production/2047793/0/0/1/ssd1306.html

"""

#import os
#os.environ['PYGAME_HIDE_SUPPORT_PROMPT'] = "hide"
from smbus import SMBus
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
#import pygame

### I2C usage ###

bus = SMBus(1)  # Create a new I2C bus
addr = 0x3C  # Address of i2c device (128x64) 
wth, hgh = 132, 64  # My sh1106 device memory is 132x64.
reg = 0x00  # Write to registers w/wo data
mem = 0x40  # Write to display memory

### Commands ###

DspClk    = 0xD5  # Display Clock (needs 1 data)
ClkData   = 0x80  # (default 80)
MuxRatio  = 0xA8  # Multiplex Ratio  (needs 1 data)
RatioData = 0x3F  # (0x3F default)
DspSlp    = 0xAE  # Display off (sleep)
DspOn     = 0xAF  # Display on
DspCts    = 0x81  # Contrast (needs 1 data)
CtsData   = 0x30  # (0x7F default) Adjust to your needs.
DspRamOff = 0xA5  # Entire display on, ignore ram
DspRamOn  = 0xA4  # Display on, ram on
DspInv    = 0xA7  # Display inverted
DspNor    = 0xA6  # Display normal
ColStartL = 0x00  # Column start address lower nibble For Page
ColStartH = 0x10  # Column start address upper nibble For Page
MemAddrMd = 0x20  # Memory address mode (needs 1 of 3 data) *1
PageData  = 0x02  # Page Addressing Mode (0x02 default) *1
RamStart  = 0x40  # Ram display start
SegMap    = 0xA0  # Segment remap
Pg0       = 0xB0  # Start page For Page (B0 - B7)
ComNor    = 0xC0  # Set COM Output Scan Direction (default)
ComRev    = 0xC8  # Set COM Output Scan Direction (remapped)
DspOfSet  = 0xD3  # Set Display Offset (needs 1 data)
OfSetData = 0     # (0 default)
# *1 not needed for sh1106 displays

### Setup ###

def wrcmd(cmd):
    bus.write_byte_data(addr, reg, cmd)

def wrram(data):
    bus.write_byte_data(addr, mem, data)

def dsploc(col_start=0, pg=0):  # Display Column Start and Page location
    col_start += 2              # memory = 132 bits, display = 128 pixels
    ColStartL = col_start % 16
    ColStartH = col_start // 16 + 0x10
    for cmd in [(Pg0 + pg), ColStartL, ColStartH]:
        wrcmd(cmd)

def clrmem():
    dsploc()
    for x in range(hgh // 8):
        wrcmd(Pg0 + x)
        for y in range(wth):
            wrram(0x00)

def setup():
    for cmd in [DspClk, ClkData, MuxRatio, RatioData, DspOfSet, OfSetData,
                DspOn, DspCts, CtsData, DspRamOn, DspNor, MemAddrMd,
                PageData, RamStart, SegMap]:  # *1 MemAddrMd, PageData
        wrcmd(cmd)                            # not needed for sh1106.
    clrmem()


def Test():
    for w in (0xFF, 0x49):
        for x in range(hgh // 8):
            wrcmd(Pg0 + x)
            for y in range(wth):
                wrram(w)
                sleep(.003)

setup()
#Test(); clrmem()  # Uncommit to run Test
#exit()  # Uncommit to exit after Test

### Fonts ###

BA = ((0x80,0xE0,0xF0,0x78,0x3C,0x1E,15,0x1E,0x3C,0x78,0xF0,0xE0,0x80,0),
      (0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x38,0x38,0x38,0x38,0x38,0x38,0x38,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (15,15,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,15,15,0))

BD = ((0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,15,15,15,15,15,0x1E,0x3E,0xFC,0xF8,0xE0,0),
      (0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,0,0,0,0x80,0xC0,0xFF,0xFF,0x7F,0),
      (15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,7,7,3,1,0,0))

BF = ((0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,0),
      (0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,0,0,0),
      (15,15,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))

BJ = ((15,15,15,15,15,15,15,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,15,15,15,0),
      (0xE0,0xC0,0x80,0,0,0,0x80,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,0,0),
      (1,3,7,15,15,15,15,15,7,3,0,0,0,0))

BM = ((0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x3C,0xF0,0xC0,0,0xC0,0xF0,0x3C,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,3,15,3,0,0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (15,15,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,15,15,0))

BN = ((0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x3C,0xF0,0xC0,0,0,0,0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,3,15,0x3C,0xF0,0xC0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (15,15,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,15,15,15,0))

BO = ((0xE0,0xF8,0xFC,0x3E,0x1E,15,15,15,0x1E,0x3E,0xFC,0xF8,0xE0,0),
      (0x7F,0xFF,0xFF,0xC0,0x80,0,0,0,0x80,0xC0,0xFF,0xFF,0x7F,0),
      (0,1,3,7,7,15,15,15,7,7,3,1,0,0))

BS = ((0xF0,0xFC,0xFE,0x9F,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,0,0),
      (0,3,7,15,15,15,15,15,15,0x9F,0xFE,0xFC,0xF0,0),
      (15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,7,3,0,0))

BT = ((15,15,15,15,15,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,15,15,15,15,15,0),
      (0,0,0,0,0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,0,0,0,0),
      (0,0,0,0,0,15,15,15,0,0,0,0,0,0))

BW = ((0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xC0,0xF0,0x3C,15,0x3C,0xF0,0xC0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (15,15,15,3,0,0,0,0,0,3,15,15,15,0))

Ma = ((0,0,0,0x80,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0x80,0,0,0),
      (0,0xFC,0xFF,0xFF,0xE7,0xE3,0xE3,0xE7,0xFF,0xFF,0xFC,0),
      (0,15,15,15,0,0,0,0,15,15,15,0))

Mb = ((0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x80,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0x80,0,0),
      (0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,3,3,3,3,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (0,15,15,15,7,15,15,15,15,7,3,0))

Mc = ((0,0,0x80,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0x80,0),
      (0,0xFE,0xFF,0xFF,0x87,3,3,3,3,3,0x87,0),
      (0,1,7,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,7,0))

Md = ((0,0,0x80,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0x80,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (0,0xFE,0xFF,0xFF,0x87,3,3,3,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (0,1,7,15,15,15,15,15,7,15,15,0))

Me = ((0,0,0x80,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0x80,0,0),
      (0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x33,0x31,0x31,0x31,0x31,0x3F,0x3F,0),
      (0,1,7,15,15,14,14,14,14,14,7,0))

Mg = ((0,0,0x80,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0x80,0),
      (0,0x7F,0xFF,0xFF,0xC1,0xC1,0xC1,0xC1,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (0,0x30,0x70,0x71,0x71,0x71,0x71,0x71,0x3F,0x3F,0x1F,0))

Mh = ((0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0,0),
      (0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,7,3,3,3,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (0,15,15,15,0,0,0,0,15,15,15,0))

Mi = ((0,0,0,0,0x1E,0x1E,0x1E,0,0,0,0,0),
      (0,0,0,0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,0,0,0),
      (0,0,0,0,15,15,15,0,0,0,0,0))

Ml = ((0,0,3,3,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,0,0,0),
      (0,0,0,0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,0,0,0),
      (0,0,0,0,7,15,15,15,15,0,0,0))

Mn = ((0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0,0),
      (0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,7,3,3,3,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (0,15,15,15,0,0,0,0,15,15,15,0))

Mo = ((0,0,0x80,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0x80,0,0),
      (0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,3,3,3,3,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (0,3,7,15,15,15,15,15,15,7,3,0))

Mp = ((0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0x80,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0x80,0,0),
      (0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xC1,0xC1,0xC1,0xC1,0xFF,0xFF,0x7F,0),
      (0,0x7F,0x7F,0x7F,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0))

Mr = ((0,0,0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0,0x80,0x80,0x80,0,0),
      (0,0,0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x0F,0x07,0x07,0x07,0x0F,0),
      (0,0,0,15,15,15,0,0,0,0,0,0))

Mt = ((0,0xF0,0xF0,0xF0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xF0,0xF0,0xF0,0xF0,0),
      (0,0,0,0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,0,0,0),
      (0,0,0,0,7,15,15,15,15,15,0,0))

Mu = ((0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0,0,0,0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0),
      (0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,0,0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (0,3,7,15,15,15,15,15,15,7,7,0))

Mv = ((0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0,0,0,0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0),
      (0,7,0x3F,0xFF,0xFC,0xC0,0xC0,0xFC,0xFF,0x3F,7,0),
      (0,0,0,0,3,15,15,3,0,0,0,0))

My = ((0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0,0,0,0,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0,0),
      (0,7,0x3F,0xFF,0xFC,0xC0,0xC0,0xFC,0xFF,0x3F,7,0),
      (0,0x70,0x70,0x70,0x71,0x3F,0x3F,0x1F,1,0,0,0))

D0 = ((0,0xFC,0xFE,0xFF,0x1F,15,15,15,15,0x1F,0xFF,0xFE,0xFC,0),
      (0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x80,0,0x7,0x7,0,0x80,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (0,3,7,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,7,3,0))

D1 = ((0,0,0,0x18,0x1C,0x1E,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,0,0,0),
      (0,0,0,0,0,0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,0,0,0),
      (0,0,0,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,0,0))

D2 = ((0,0x1E,0x1E,15,15,15,15,15,15,0x1E,0xFE,0xFC,0xF8,0),
      (0,0,0x80,0xC0,0xE0,0xF0,0x78,0x3C,0x1E,15,7,3,1,0),
      (0,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,0))

D3 = ((0,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,0x9F,0xFE,0xFC,0xF8,0),
      (0,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,0x9F,0xF9,0xF9,0xF0,0),
      (0,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,7,3,1,0))

D4 = ((0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,0,0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0,0,0),
      (0,15,15,15,14,14,14,14,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,14,14,0),
      (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,15,15,0,0,0))

D5 = ((0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,0,0),
      (0,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,0x9F,0xFE,0xFC,0xF0,0),
      (0,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,7,3,0,0))

D6 = ((0,0xF0,0xFC,0xFE,0x1F,15,15,15,15,15,0,0,0,0),
      (0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x8F,7,7,7,7,0x8F,0xFF,0xFE,0xFC,0),
      (0,3,7,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,7,3,0))

D7 = ((0,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,0xCF,0xFF,0xFF,0x3F,0),
      (0,0,0,0,0,0xC0,0xF0,0xFC,0x3F,15,0x03,0,0,0),
      (0,0,0,12,15,15,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))

D8 = ((0,0xFC,0xFE,0xFF,0x9F,15,15,15,15,0x9F,0xFF,0xFE,0xFC,0),
      (0,0xF0,0xF9,0xFF,0x8F,7,7,7,7,0x8F,0xFF,0xF9,0xF0,0),
      (0,3,7,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,7,3,0))

D9 = ((0,0xFC,0xFE,0xFF,0x1F,15,15,15,15,0x1F,0xFF,0xFE,0xFC,0),
      (0,3,7,15,15,14,14,14,14,0x8F,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0),
      (0,0,0,0,0,15,15,15,15,15,7,3,0,0))

sp = ((0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))  # space

cl = ((0,0,0xF0,0xF0,0xF0,0xF0,0,0),  # colon
      (0,0,0xF0,0xF0,0xF0,0xF0,0,0),
      (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))

cm = ((0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),              # comma + space
      (0,0,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0,0,0,0,0),
      (0,0,0x67,0x77,0x7F,0x3F,0,0,0,0,0))

t0 = ((0,0x84,0xC6,0xE6,0xB6,0x9E,0x8C,0),  # 20 vertical stacked
      (0,0xE1,0xF1,0x31,0x31,0xF1,0xE1,0),
      (0,3,7,6,6,7,3,0))

t1 = ((0,0x84,0xC6,0xE6,0xB6,0x9E,0x8C,0),  # 21 vertical stacked
      (0,1,0x21,0xF1,0xF1,1,1,0),
      (0,0,6,7,7,6,0,0))

wk = ((BS,Mu,Mn), (BM,Mo,Mn), (BT,Mu,Me), (BW,Me,Md),   # week days
      (BT,Mh,Mu), (BF,Mr,Mi), (BS,Ma,Mt))

num = (D0,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9)                   # numbers

mth = ((),(BJ,Ma,Mn),(BF,Me,Mb),(BM,Ma,Mr),(BA,Mp,Mr),  # months
       (BM,Ma,My),(BJ,Mu,Mn),(BJ,Mu,Ml),(BA,Mu,Mg),
       (BS,Me,Mp),(BO,Mc,Mt),(BN,Mo,Mv),(BD,Me,Mc))

### Propgram to display time and date  ###
###   on an i2c display.               ###

def gtdttm():  # GeT DaTe and TiMe
    fdttm = datetime.now()
    dttm = fdttm.strftime("%w %m %b %d %Y %a %I:%M")
    return dttm.split()

def rnfnt(fnt, lngh, start, pg=0):  # ReNder 1 FoNT
    for x in range(3):              # Fonts use 3 pages per charature.
        dsploc(start, x + pg)       # Set start and page per character.
        for y in range(lngh):
            z = fnt[x][y]
            wrram(z)

def sufnt(fntts, ix, dom=None):  # SetUp FoNT TypeS, IndeX, Day Or Month
    fix = dttm[ix]               # Field of DaTe TiMe by IndeX
    arfnts = []; arlnghs = []     # Font list, font lenght list
    for w in range(len(fntts)):  # Set font type to font.
        if dom: fnt = dom[int(fix)][w]  # Alph only charatures
        elif fntts[w] == "D": fnt = num[int(fix[w])]
        elif fntts[w] == ":": fnt = cl
        elif fntts[w] == ",": fnt = cm
        elif fntts[w] == "t": fnt = t0 if fix[w] == "0" else t1
        arfnts.append(fnt)
        arlnghs.append(len(fnt[0]))
    return arfnts, arlnghs

def dspan(fnts, lnghs, start, pg):  # DiSPlay selected Alp-Num charatures
    for w in range(len(lnghs)):
            fnt = fnts[w]
            rnfnt(fnt, lnghs[w], start, pg)
            start += lnghs[w] + 1

def blink(off):  # blink the colon
    start = 78; pg = 0
    if off == True: fnt = (cl); blk = True  # if off display colon
    else: fnt = (sp); blk = False           # else display space
    rnfnt(fnt, len(cl[0]), start, pg)
    return blk

### main ###
            
svdttm = []         # SaVe DaTe and TiMe
for x in range(8):  # Save area for Date and Time
    svdttm.append(" ")
#print(gtdttm())
wd = 0; mn = 1; dy = 3; yr = 4; ct = 6  # index dttm, WeekDay, MoNth#,...
blk = False  # BLinK = off

### Loop starts here ###

while True:

    dttm = gtdttm()  # DaTe & TiMe; wk#,mth#,month,day,year,weekday,H:M
    
    if dttm[wd] != svdttm[wd]:  # Day of the Week; 0:Sunday, 1:Monday
        start = 0; pg = 0
        fntts = ("B", "M", "M")  # FoNT TypeS, Big & Medium size
        fnts, lnghs = sufnt(fntts, wd, wk)
        dspan(fnts, lnghs, start, pg)
        svdttm[wd] = dttm[wd]

    if dttm[ct] != svdttm[ct]:  # Current Time; hour:minute
        start = 48; pg = 0
        fntts = ("D", "D", ":", "D", "D")
        fnts, lnghs = sufnt(fntts, ct)
        dspan(fnts, lnghs, start, pg)
        blk = True
        svdttm[ct] = dttm[ct]
    elif blk == True: blk = blink(False)
    else: blk = blink(True)

    if dttm[mn] != svdttm[mn]:  # Month Number; 1:January
        start = 0; pg = 4
        fntts = ("B", "M", "M")
        fnts, lnghs = sufnt(fntts, mn, mth)
        dspan(fnts, lnghs, start, pg)
        svdttm[mn] = dttm[mn]

    if dttm[dy] != svdttm[dy]:  # DaY of the month
        start = 48; pg = 4
        fntts = ("D", "D")
        fnts, lnghs = sufnt(fntts, dy)
        dspan(fnts, lnghs, start, pg)
        svdttm[dy] = dttm[dy]

    if dttm[yr] != svdttm[yr]:
        start = 78; pg = 4
        fntts = (",", "t", "D", "D")
        fnts, lnghs = sufnt(fntts, yr)
        dspan(fnts, lnghs, start, pg)
        svdttm[yr] = dttm[yr]

    sleep(1)  # Sleep a second before update(s) and blink the colon.
```